# D3 highlighting according to a part of the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my data(JSON) and the data is 150,000+ lines like this. I am using this data to draw the nodes and the lines between the nodes in D3, I have really good code for that.

```
"nodes" : [{
            "id" : "r75832",
            "name" : "name1",
            "x" : 1209,
            "y" : 41
        }, {
            "id" : "q26475",
            "name" : "name2",
            "x" : 483,
            "y" : 227
        }, 
.
.
.

"links" : [{
            "id" : "abc ",
            "name" : "t5.4.6.2 , 4.5.0.7, p00738",
            "x1" : 348,
            "y1" : 341,
            "x2" : 349,
            "y2" : 340,
            "x3" : 351,
            "y3" : 340,
            "x4" : 350,
            "y4" : 341
        }, {
            "id" : "def ",
            "name" : "a1.2.3.4 , 6.7.8.9, b00574",
            "x1" : 349,
            "y1" : 340,
            "x2" : 349,
            "y2" : 339,
            "x3" : 351,
            "y3" : 339,
            "x4" : 351,
            "y4" : 340
        },
.
.
.
```

I also have a piece of code to make a dropdown menu something like:

```
'E met' : {
  'a met' : {
    'M00175 name1' : {},
   },
  'b met' : {
    'M00567 name2' : {},
    'M00174 name3' : {},
   },

.
.
.
}
```

What I want is that when on the drop down menu when someone click on M00174 I want some nodes to be highlighted and when someone click on M00567 some other nodes to be highlighted that belong to M00567 and so on.

I am stuck at this point how to define that specific piece of data to make them highlight in between 150,000+ lines of code and also how to make them highlight. Any ideas?

Comment: did the answer help ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy What I want is that [link] (http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/atlas/?01100) on this website there are checkboxes on the left hand side when you check one of them it highlights something on the map. Instead making checkboxes I created a dropdown menu. It doesn't do anything now. I want it to have the same functionality as checkboxes that is on the website I gave you.

Comment: So whats so hard about that ? Just do what I did, instead implement a select drop down where you can select multiple items. Then instead of filtering the nodes on group, filter them on ID's and make sure these ID's are in the drop down. So easy to expand what I did to what you want

Comment: Also if you want to do the links too, youll have to select them by class as if i remember your data you had multiple links with the same class

Comment: @thisOneGuy okay sure I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is just call a function on change of the drop down. And then loop the nodes to give them a border (highlighted).

Here is a fiddle I have put together : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/dFK3K/287/

First off I made an array of all the different groups that are in this set of data :

```
var arrayOfGroups = [];

function makearray() {

  node.each(function(d) {
    if (arrayOfGroups.indexOf(d.group) < 0) {
      arrayOfGroups.push(d.group)
    }
  })
  console.log(arrayOfGroups)
  return arrayOfGroups;
}
```

What this basically does is go through each node and if the array i created hasn't got that group in, it pushes the group in to it.

Then I create a drop down based on this array :

```
function creatSelectDropDown(id, array) {

  var dropdown = document.createElement("select");
  dropdown.id = id;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = array[i];
    option.value = array[i];
    dropdown.options.add(option);
  }


  return dropdown; //return drop down list
}
```

Get the container(I added a div in the html ) :

```
var container = document.getElementById('selectContainer')
```

Get the generated drop down :

```
var dropdown = creatSelectDropDown('thisDropdown', newArray);
```

Appended this created select drop down to the container :

```
container.appendChild(dropdown)
```

Then created an on change function :

```
dropdown.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log(event)
  node.style('stroke', 'white') //this is to set all nodes to default stroke
    .style('stroke-width', '1px');

  node.filter(function(d) {
      return d.group == event.target.value;
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      console.log('d')
    })
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('stroke-width', '5px')
}
```

What this does is get the value of the select on change, use this value to filter the nodes that have a group that equals that value.

And that's it. When you change the drop down, it gets the value of the option in the drop down, filters the nodes to those that have a group equal to the option tag and adds a stroke to all those nodes :)

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: @D.Ister added to answer. This is using the data from this force layout : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045